# Bash get md5sum of File not path as String

Tags: bash, md5sum

I'm trying to save the md5sum of multiple java files in a text file, but as I see it, it creates an md5sum of the path and not the file itself.

```
find $FilesDirectory -iregex '.*\.java' | while read line; do

if [ -f "$line" ] 
    then
        echo -n $line | md5sum.exe | cut -d' ' -f1 | tr -d '\n' >> $FileName
        echo -n "-" >> $FileName
        echo -n $line | cut -d' ' -f2 >> $FileName
    fi
done
```

I'm also trying to eliminate any newline except for the last one.
When I changed the path for the md5sum to a file that didn't exist it still made an md5sum.
(I am using MINGW Shell)

Comment: `md5sum.exe "$line" | cut ... `

Comment: `for line in *.java`

Comment: Why fo you have an `.exe` suffix? Are you on Cygwin?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm trying it right now but i'll have to run a test for somewhat 30mins until I can be sure it's correct. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may be able to replace the entire script with `md5sum.exe *.java` - depending on the implementation of `md5sum.exe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply worried about outputting the md5sum and filename to a file in the format `md5sum-filename`, then you can simply use **pattern expansion** and **substring extraction** to read the md5sum of a file (where ever it may live) and remove the path information leaving only the name to output:

```
find $FilesDirectory -iregex '.*\.java' | while read line; do

if [ -f "$line" ] 
    then
        md5str="$(md5sum "$line")"
        sum=${md5str%% *}
        sumfn=${md5str##* }
        sumfn=${sumfn##*/}

        echo "$sum-$sumfn" >> $FileName
    fi
done
```

Comment: Well this seems rather perfect. I'll test this for a while and come back to you but so far I seem happy with this answer thank you.

Comment: Thank you again I ran a pretty large test and everything was Perfect. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `md5sum` without a file name reads its data (not its arguments) from standard input, and calculates a checksum for that.

Tangentially, `echo filename | xargs md5sum` is a workaround if you really need to read arguments from stdin.

But here, you have no reason to want to do that.

```
find "$FilesDirectory" -type f -iregex '.*\.java' \
    -exec md5sum + |
sed 's%  *.*/%-%' >"$FileName"
```

The `-type f` replaces `if [ -f ...` and the `-exec ... +` runs `md5sum` on all the found files. Then we simply post-process the output to put a dash instead of a run of spaces after the checksum. The regular expression matches spaces, then any character up to the last slash, and replaces it all. Thus it also removes the path name.

(If you have an old version of `find` you may have to use `-exec md5sum {} \;` instead.)

If all the files are in the current directory, and there are no directories which match the wildcard (in which case `-type f` is superfluous above, too) and there are not so many as to cause the wildcard to expand to a steing which is too long ("argument list too long") you can simply do

```
md5sum *.[jJ][aA][vV][aA] | ...
```

If you need to use `find` and you have subdirectories but don't want it to traverse them, add `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: Well I tried this but it says:
"find: missing argument to `-exec´" 
After I searched for exec online I only found ways to redirect an stdin to a file using the filename as an argument. But I don't see how to use it in this case.

Comment: That's an indication that `-exec ... +` is not supported by your `find`. Try the `-exec ... {} \;` variant instead.